# Best way to structure a Meteor app for multiple organizations?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I want to allow  my meteor app to have siloed organizations/teams that essentially have separate databases. They can only see their own content/users.

What is the most efficient way for me to set this up?

Options that I can think of:

1. Every user & piece of content has an associated organization ID
2. Each org has a separate instance of the app with its own separate DB

Comment: The simplest way would probably be running several instances of your app, and specifying a MONGO_URL for each. Would that solve your problem?

Comment: I imagine that wouldn't be the best solution if we want people to be able to sign up on the fly and have thousands of different accounts.